# logs are printed on command line

Tags: python, logging

I have a python script running as a daemon on an ubuntu. In the script, I am using logging module to write the logs to a logfile.  All my handlers are created base on this logfile. when it is running, logs were logged in the file correctly but they are printed on the command line as well. anyone know why is that? How could I stop it printing on command line?

Comment: How are you logging? Are they just `print` statements or are you using a module like `logging` to handle it?

Comment: Yes. I am using the logging module.

Comment: did you created a logger that you import, or just import the logging module with basic config ?

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to initialize the logging module? My guess is that you're using the `basicConfig()` command which enables it by default.

Comment: Post the code you are using, along with the output, so we can tell what is going on.